# SVG ds.js - why does an append operation on defs modifies the data binding of svg selectAll

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, meteor, append

In this meteor based d3 svg application, a simple drawing pad is setup. The circle tool is used as the primary brush. Patterns are added to svg. Button click loads the id of the selected pattern to the parameter which is sent to the d3.svg and further it adds pattern to the circle tool. Then i wanted to add specific color to the patterns using mask, and that returned error as type error: "d" is undefined. "d" was the data parameter used for the `selectAll` data binding, which didn't give any error before adding mask.

On the d3 svg JS client side:

```
    Canvas = function() {
        var self = this;
        var svg;

        var createSvg = function() {
            svg = d3.select('#canvas').append('svg')
            .attr('width', window.innerWidth * 0.8)   //800
            .attr('height', window.innerHeight * 0.8);   //600
        };

        createSvg();

        self.clear = function() {
            d3.select('svg').remove();
            createSvg();
        };

        self.drawCircs = function(data) {
        if(data.length < 1) {
            self.clear();
            return;
        } 

        if (svg) {

            var defs = svg.append('defs');

                defs.append("mask")
                    .attr('id', "crayonMask")
                .append('ellipse')
                    .attr('cx', '0')
                    .attr('cy', '0')
                    .attr('rx', '100%')
                    .attr('ry', '100%')
                    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.3")
                    .attr('fill', "url(#crayon)");

                defs.append('pattern')
                    .attr('id', "crayon")  
                    .attr('patternUnits', "objectBoundingBox")
                    .attr('patternContentUnits', "userSpaceOnUse")
                    .attr('width', "36")
                    .attr('height', "16")
                .append('image')
                    .attr('xlink:href', "http://www.onlygfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/crayon-scribble-banner-2.png")
                    .attr('x', "0")
                    .attr('y', "0")
                    .attr('width', "36")
                    .attr('height', "16");

                 svg.selectAll('circle').data(data, function(d){ return d._id; }) 
                .enter().append('circle')
                .attr('cx', function(d){ return d.x; })
                .attr('cy', function(d){ return d.y; })
                .attr('r', function(d){ return d.w; })
                .attr("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.o; })
                .attr('mask', "url(#" + d.ptrnId + "Mask)")   
                .attr('fill', function (d) {if(d.ptrnId === ""){ 
                    console.log("circle brush pattern selected!"); 
                    return d.c; 
                } else {
                        console.log(d.ptrnId + " brush pattern selected!"); 
                        return d.c;   //"url(#" + d.ptrnId + ")"; 
                    }})   
                ;

        }
    };
}
```

On the user-based events client side: 
For reference, this is how data object is being sent to d3.

```
var markPoint = function(event) {
  var offset = $("#canvas").offset();

  if(lastX == 0) {
    lastX = (event.pageX - offset.left);
    lastY = (event.pageY - offset.top);
  }

  points.insert({
    dateTime: new Date(),
    toolType: toolType,
    x: (event.pageX - offset.left),
    y: (event.pageY - offset.top),
    x1: lastX,
    y1: lastY,
    w: thickness,
    c: strokeColor,
    o: opacity,
    ptrnId: brushPattern

  });

    // updating last point
    lastX = (event.pageX - offset.left);
    lastY = (event.pageY - offset.top);
}
```

Without the append mask, the select all data binding works perfectly. The output is a circle stroke with pattern fill. But upon appending mask onto the defs on the svg, the data binding '(d)' returns undefined.

I even changed the mask from circle to an ellipse to avoid selecting mask circle for selectAll('circle').

I have been stuck with this problem for quite sometime. The rest of the app basically builds on several patterns but with mask not working, it all falls down. Please help me out.

P.S. - This is my first time asking a question in here, so please excuse me for the poor structuring of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to access `d` in a string, whereas you should be doing

`.attr("mask", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.ptrnId + "Mask)"; })`

Comment: Thanks @Danail, that was a silly oversight from me which i couldn't locate, till you pointed that out. I must add that the reference error for 'd' comes back upon using the same element type as that of the `selectAll` binding i.e. 'circle', when used for creating a mask or a pattern. So I had to go stick to ellipses for creating masks and patterns. Thanks, now I am onto fixing the masking irregularities.